# Django queries and translatable models

Tags: django, postgresql

My application has many models that can have 0 or more translations. I chose to put the translation in seperate tables:

```
MyModel()
    reference = text
    is_deleted = boolean
    updated_on = datetime


MyModelTrans()
    parent = MyModel
    name = text
```

*Note that the API implements softdelete through is_deleted and incremental update through updated_on (a bit simplified here).*

My question is: is there a way to get the whole dataset in 1 single query with Django ORM? I want all MyModel instances to be returned along with their (optional) translations.

First I wanted to accomplish this by simply querying the MyModelTrans() table with a select_related to 'parent', but then I realised that not all
MyModels will have translations.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prefetch_related`. It's used for selecting related models along with models in an efficient manner. See more here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

For example, you could write the following.

```
MyModel.objects.all().prefetch_related("translations")
```

You will need to set `related_name` in your ForeignKey definition for MyModelTrans.

```
parent = ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name="translations")
```

One query will be executed for selecting your model instances, and another query will be executed for selecting the related fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already knew what you suggest, and I indicate it in my post. My question is what kind of query we're looking for to also support main objects that MAY NOT have any translations.